# Using php logic (at little dose) in view, is justified for MVC concept?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am read about MVC pattern, that whole php logic must be in model, but when we have situation like this: from model passed `mysqli_result` object to view and in view we need check value from some column (mysql table column) and print something according to this value, that is in *view* we have:

```
while ($row = $my_mysqli_result_object->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['some_column'] == "1") {
        // print something
    }
    else if ($row['some_column'] == "2") {
        // print something other
    }
    else if ($row['some_column'] == "3") {
        // print something other
    }
    // ....
    // ....
}
```

As you see, in view is php logic (few logic , but exists).

My question is: this dose of php logic in view, normally for MVC concept ? or this is not right way for MVC and must do something other, in such situations?

Comment: You shouldn't be passing mysqli resources to the view. Or out of the model at all.

Comment: Ok, I make `mysql_query` in model and now want print this obtained data, so what make if: `You shouldn't be passing mysqli resources to the view` ?

Comment: @metal_fan beat me to it. Were both suggesting the same thing. This is essentially what any PHP framework provides you with. My personal choice for my mobile site with mobile apps was Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC pattern all the logic is in the controller, not in the model.

The model usually carry only the data. It could verify data correctness (that's the only elaboration delegated to the model).

The view can do few elaboration - i.e. it can have a little bit of logic inside - but only if it is related to the presentation aspect.

Answering to your question: this dose of php logic in view is absolutely normal and acceptable.

Comment: In this simple case though, the function is retrieving data from the database, he just needs to pass in which "some_column" he is interested in, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Then, what's the logic you put inside the model?

Comment: See my answer below. Call the public static function in the model class, passing it the "type" of column youre looking for and handle accordingly.

Comment: @jamis0n But in your case, we obtain `HTML` code in model, this is right way?

Comment: @all 1) Model should not should not print anything 2) Model should not be affected by type of request 3) Model should not handle global vars like `$_POST`, `$_GET` - instead you should pass them via controller to Model

Comment: @jamis0n in the model you should never have any presentation part.  The model should be as easy as possible, consider a class that have only getter and setter. Model could notify its associated views and controllers when there has been a change in its state. In many frameworks I saw the model check the data correctness. That's all.

Comment: @freedev I completely agree. I sometimes use functions in the model to return JSON datasets, which are then handled by Javascript. It all depends how much effort/complexity are involved.

Comment: @jamis0n please don't call me hardliner ;) but even in this case you shouldn't. All the presentation part is delegated to the view: HTML, json, charts or PDF.

Comment: @freedev: JSON is not presentation. JSON is data interchange. It's quite right to return that kind of thing from a model call. But _not_ HTML, PDFs, MySQL resources...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Please try to imagine this web app as a service, may be a REST service. It returns any kind of format. HTML can be consumed by a browser, PDF too or may be another client, like charts and json. Json could be consumed by a JavaScript browser side or another web apps. Adopting this patter left you free to have multiple clients consuming same resources.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And presentation part should have the responsibility to convert the model in the correct format, accordingly with controller logic. (Btw, I don't remember I have mentioned MySql resources in my comment)

Comment: @freedev: The OP is passing MySQL resources from his model. Emitting JSON is fine as JSON is not tied to MySQL or to HTML or to PDF - it is _raw data_. That data, coming out of your model, then goes into your view which decides how to render it for human consumption.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for your answer. I really had no time to follow the thread, I apologize to being disappeared.  I still don't get exactly all your thoughts. Maybe because I'm not a native english guy. In any case, this thread becomes too long for this place. When I have time I'll try to write a clear question on this argument.

Answer (score 5):

#### Some general info about MVC

Each part of MVC design pattern has specific roles. It is done by introducing two kinds of separations (concept introduced by [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle):

- *Model layer* <sup>[*[1]*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208)</sup> and *Presentation layer* within the system isolates domain business rules from visual representation
- *Controllers* and *Views* inside presentation layer makes sure that UI generation and user input are unattached to each other

Actually, when you look at properly designed *model layer*, it also amalgamation of different structures for different tasks: application logic, domain logic or storage logic.

#### What are the Views?

There is a common misconception, mostly perpetuated by Rails <sup>[*[2]*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984678/727208)</sup> fans and frameworks, which try to emulate it. **View is not a dumb template**.

Within modern interpretation of MVC, when applied for web, the Views are instances, which contain most of the UI logic. Yes, logic. View should acquire information from model layer and, based on the data it got, decide what response to produce and which templates does it need to assemble that response.

The *`how`* for acquisition of data is one of the primary factors that separated MVC-inspired patterns like Model2 MVC, MVVM and MVP.

### ..now actually about the original question:

The code. that you showed should be split, because it has two distinct goals: information retrieval from storage and making decisions about the output. The `fetch_assoc()` bit should go into *Model layer* (most likely, within some [*data mapper*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) instance. And your `switch( $someColumn )` statement should be move to the view instance.

> <sub>As a bit unrelated note, the example made me think, that you are actually dealing there with some `status` column there. In that case it is a good idea to drop the `if/else` with and just use `$status = $listOfOption[ $someColumn ]`, where `$listOfOptions = [0 => 'error', 1 => 'pending', 2 => 'unconfirmed', 3 => 'complete'];` ... or something along the lines</sub>

Your view should be one deciding how to represent that column and what value must be bound to templates.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I agree. Talking about the View may I add only two important things: first that into one MVC implementation there could be multiple Views. Because if we think at a web app as a service, the output format could depends from the client needing (html, json, xml, images, etc.). This is another benefit of this beautiful pattern. Second, that even if the View return a response in a simple format like json, it is usually there, in the view the part, where the model should be transformed into json. Even if there are only one or two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could tuck that function into the PHP model class, and call it in the view with 1 line of code.

MyModelClass.php

```
class MyModelClass {

    public static function getData($someColumn)
        //Do Query and get result
        $data_array = null;
        while ($row = $my_mysqli_result_object->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($someColumn == "1") {
                    // print something
            }
            else if ($someColumn == "2") {
                // print something other
            }
            else if ($someColumn == "3") {
                // print something other
            }
            // ....
            // .... BUILD DATASET ARRAY
            // ....
         }
         return $data_array;
     }
}
```